# C - How can I print out different strings for the outcome of an evaluated expression?

Tags: c, string, char

I have a loop that prints out different BMI values for 10 users in this format:

```
                        USER    BMI    STATUS
                        1
                        :
                        10
```

The BMI Statuses are strings `"Overweight", "Normal" , "Underweight", and "Obese"`

1. Underweight - When the BMI is less than 18.50
2. Normal - When the BMI is from 18.50 to 24.9
3. Overweight - When the BMI is from 25.0 to 29.9
4. Obese - When the BMI is greater than 30.0

I already figured out how to print out the BMI values on new lines from the awesome answers I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637623/how-can-i-pull-this-off-in-c) but I'm still finding it hard to display the BMI Statuses.

Here's what I have,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    float weight_value[10];
    float user_height[10];
    float BMI = 0.0f;
    char* BMI_Status[] = {"Underweight", "Normal", "Overweight", "Obese"};

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        printf("Please enter your weight: "); 
        scanf("%f", &weight_value[i]);  //Reads in the user's weight and stores it in an array
        printf("Now enter your height: ");
        scanf("%f", &user_height[i]); //Reads in the user's height and stores it in an array.
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("USER                 BMI                  STATUS\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        BMI = weight_value[i] / (user_height[i] * user_height[i]);
        printf("%2d %23.7f \n", i+1 , BMI );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I created an array of characters that holds the BMI Status strings, but since these are strings that are going to be deduced from expressions in the code, I have no idea how to print them on every line.

I thought of using `if` conditions to test for when the BMI values are true, but when I get to the part where I'm to add the argument that prints out the BMI Status string, I get confused.

Comment: what is the problem with `if`? You can continue after getting the value of `BMI`

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried doing that, but I'm finding it difficult printing out the different `BMI_Status[]` strings at every iteration of the second loop.

Comment: consider a variable flag,  if bmi < 18.50, do flag = 0, else if 18.50 < bmi < 24.9, set flag = 1.... after that, simply print BMI_Status[flag]

Comment: How is the answer in [your (badly titled) previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637623/how-can-i-pull-this-off-in-c) not useful?

Comment: @Jongware There was more than one question in the previous question and I couldn't think of a better way to put the question without it being too long.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you so much, Your last comment answered my question, I didn't get it at first, but after reading it one more time, I finally got it. Why don't you post this as an answer instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the status according to the BMI calculated, you need to choose the proper index of the array holding the status value. You can achieve the same using a separate variable. Check the below code to get an idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

        float weight_value[10];
        float user_height[10];
        float BMI = 0.0f;
        char* BMI_Status[] = {"Underweight", "Normal", "Overweight", "Obese"};

        int i;

        int flag = -1;    //used as index

        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
                printf("Please enter your weight: ");
                scanf("%f", &weight_value[i]);  //Reads in the user's weight and stores it in an array
                printf("Now enter your height: ");
                scanf("%f", &user_height[i]); //Reads in the user's height and stores it in an array.
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("USER                 BMI                  STATUS\n");

        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
                BMI = weight_value[i] / (user_height[i] * user_height[i]);
                //after getting the BMI value, select the string index to be printed
                if (BMI < 18.5)
                {
                                flag = 0;
                }
                else if ((BMI > 18.5) && (BMI < 24.9 ))
                {
                                flag = 1;
                }
                else if ((BMI > 24.9) && (BMI < 29.9 ))
                {
                                flag = 2;
                }
                else if (BMI > 30)
                {
                                flag = 3;
                }

                printf("%2d %23.7f \t\t%s\n", i+1 , BMI, BMI_Status[flag] );    //print the stats
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Note : You may want to add some checks to validate the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need every thing on one line you could write the mother of all tertiary operator expressions:

```
 printf("%2d %23.7f %23s", i+1, BMI, BMI_Status[(BMI<18.5 ? 0 : (BMI < 24.9 ? 1 : (BMI < 29.9 ? 2 : 3)))])
```

In reality, this is just the if-elseif-else style from Joe M's answer rolled into a single line.  Please note, I would never write something like this in production code, but rather
something the others have suggested.